# I want to create a loop with a large dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

#### Problem

I want to create a loop from data in `df1` it's *important* the data is taken one ID value at a time.

I'm unsure how this can be done with R.

```
#original dataset
id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
dob=c("11-08","12-04","04-03","10-04","03-07","06-02","12-09","01-01","03-08")
count=c(1,6,3,2,5,6,8,6,4)
outcome=rep(1:0,length.out=9)
df1=data.frame(id,dob,count,outcome)

#changes for each value this needs to be completed separately for each value
df2<-df1[df1$id==1,]
df2<-df2[,-4]
addition<-df2$count+45
df2<-cbind(df2,addition)

df3<-df1[df1$id==2,]
df3<-df3[,-4]
addition<-df3$count+45
df3<-cbind(df3,addition)

df4<-df1[df1$id==3,]
df4<-df4[,-4]
addition<-df4$count+45
df4<-cbind(df4,addition)

df5<-rbind(df2,df3,df4)
```

#### Expected Output

```
df5<-rbind(df2,df3,df4)


1   1   11-08   1   46
2   1   12-04   6   51
3   1   04-03   3   48
4   2   10-04   2   47
5   2   03-07   5   50
6   2   06-02   6   51
7   3   12-09   8   53
8   3   01-01   6   51
9   3   03-08   4   49
```

Comment: You do not need a loop. Just remove fourth column and assign the new column: `df$addtion <- df$count + 45`. Even if you have to simplify, please retain close to original process for a proper [MCVE].

Comment: Imagine if further to the example I was adding information from other data frames and altering large quantities of time series data based on original info and a loop must be used

Comment: Please show (not tell) this for answerers and future readers of your post. You omitted very relevant detail.

Comment: Apologies @Parfait I was trying to retain close to original process for a proper minimal reproducible example, but thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the present context (could be a simplified example) it doesn't even need that to loop, as we can directly add the 'count' with a number

```
df1$addition <- df1$count + 45
```

---

However, if it is a complicated operation and needs to look into the 'id' separately, then do a `group_by` operation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(addition = count + 45)
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id dob   count outcome addition
#  <dbl> <fct> <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>
#1     1 11-08     1       1       46
#2     1 12-04     6       0       51
#3     1 04-03     3       1       48
#4     2 10-04     2       0       47
#5     2 03-07     5       1       50
#6     2 06-02     6       0       51
#7     3 12-09     8       1       53
#8     3 01-01     6       0       51
#9     3 03-08     4       1       49
```

---

Also, `data.table` syntax would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, addition := count + 45, by = id]
```

or simply

```
setDT(df1)[, addition := count + 45]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm manipulating time series data within this dataset, so would need to run this as a loop, but I understand that you have still answered the above question.
Edit: By this I mean thank you for answering the question, but I will be unable to use it for my specific task, due to large amount of code left out of my question.

Comment: @Sparky As I mentioned, it can be a groupby operation.

Comment: @Sparky, we are showing you do not need a loop. In fact, there is no grouping needed! Just simple column assignment.